# String matching operation

Tags: java, string, string-matching

I have two Strings (they can be anything) like `I am a boy` and `I am a man`. Where `I am a` is common. My task is to find out the common words from two strings.

I used `Set<String>` to store the data, but it only stores unique values. So my question is, how can I get common words from two Strings?

The two sentences above should, for instance, produce the result `{"I", "am", "a"}`, i.e. the set of words common to both sentences.

Comment: Use map, *key* is each string and *value* is how many times it appears.

Comment: `add()` [returns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) whether the set already contained the value. That should suffice.

Comment: Are you looking for common words, or for common substrings? To illustrate my question, would answer remain the same if I replaced "I am a boy" with "am I a boy"?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes!!

Comment: Kona, You should be more precise, What is the expected result for "I am a boy and" "I am a and man" ?

Comment: @OrelEraki "I am a and"

Comment: @KonaAhmed, Thank you. I'm removing my answer.

Comment: @KonaAhmed you will get what you want from any of my ways.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `Set<String>` better use a [`Map<String,Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that stores the occurrence count for each word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Tokenize the string and store it into a Map. Token should be as key and value should be the count for that. Now for which value is 2. Should be common.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to compute the *intersection* of two sets, where the elements in the sets are words from a sentence. `Set.retainAll(Collection)` can do that for you.

```
String str1 = "I am already a man";
String str2 = "I am but a boy";

Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str1.split(" ")));
intersection.retainAll(Arrays.asList(str2.split(" ")));

System.out.println(intersection);
```

will output `[am, a, I]`

---

`Set.retainAll(Collection)` from the javadoc:

> Retains only the elements in this set that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). In other words, removes from this set all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection.

Comment: This will not work for input "iamaboy" and "iamaman"(without any spaces between character).

Comment: but that is a completely different problem from what you were asking. what is it you want, recognize words or recognize similar character sequences? please reformulate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    String s1 = "I am a boy and";
    String s2 = "I am a man";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String i : s1.split(" ")) {
        if (s2.contains(i)) {
           sb.append(i);
           sb.append(" ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("common strings: "+sb.toString());
```

Out put:

```
    common strings: I am a
```

You can do this by using [retainAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) too.

```
    String s1 = "I am a boy and";
    String s2 = "I am a and man";
    Set<String> set1= new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s1.split(" ")));
    Set<String> set2= new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s2.split(" ")));
    set1.retainAll(set2);
    System.out.println(set1);
```

Comment: We shouldn't provide full solutions for questions that don't show efforts.

Comment: This won't work for "I am a boy and" "I am a and man". Algorithm isn't correct.

Comment: @OrelEraki you should check this again, this will give you common strings for these two.. so your case out put : `I am a and `

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera, He answered, I removed my answer.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera This will not work for input "iamaboy" and "iamaman"(without any spaces between character).

Answer (score 0):

Why not store a `Map<String, Integer>`? A string whose value is greater than 1 is what you need.

E.g. if you have two strings

```
String a = "I am a boy";
String b = "I am a man";
String[] a_words = a.split("\\s+");
String[] b_words = b.split("\\s+");

Map<String, Integer> wordCountMap = new Treemap<String, Integer>();
for (String s : a_words) ...
for (String s : b_words) ...

for (String word : wordCountMap.keySet())
    if (wordCountMap.get(word) > 1)
        System.out.println(word + " is in both strings.");
```

Note that this structure allows you to identify words that are common in `k` strings, for any `k > 0`.

If you are open to using Guava, then you could also use `Multiset<String>` instead of a map.